# Migrate from NHibernate ids (hilo) to SQL auto ids in SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate

Is there a way to migrate existing database with all tables and relations to use SQL Server auto ids instead of Nhibernate (hilo) ids?

We have a .NET application which uses NHibernate. But the problem is, we are running out of `int`.

I know that this requires tables recreation with new ones which have ids set as auto incremented. Is there a easy way to migrate. For example some sort of query which will replicate tables, keep relations, but now with SQL Server ids instead of hilo ids. Biggest problem of hilo, it's using shared `ids`, which makes situation worse.

For example, we have a database of 3 tables:

- `dbo.Users`
- `dbo.RegistrationResults`
- `dbo.UserNotes`

Tables:

`dbo.Users`

- `Id` int (Primary)
- `Email` nvarchar(255)
- `RegistrationResultFk` int (Foreign Key)

`dbo.RegistrationResults`

- `Id` int (Primary)
- `ValidationOutcome` nvarchar(255)

`dbo.UserNotes`

- `Id` int (Primary)
- `Message` nvarchar(255)
- `RegistrationResultFk` int (Foreign Key)

And data populated like this:

`dbo.Users`

| Id | Email | RegistrationResultFk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test@gmail.com | 2 |
| 4 | test2@gmail.com | 5 |

`dbo.RegistrationResults`

| Id | ValidationOutcome |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Awaiting confirmation |
| 5 | Confirmed |

`dbo.UserNotes`

| Id | Message | RegistrationResultFk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | it's a test | 2 |
| 6 | it's a test 2 | 5 |

***We want data after migration to look like:***

`dbo.Users`

| Id | Email | RegistrationResultFk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test@gmail.com | 1 |
| 2 | test2@gmail.com | 2 |

`dbo.RegistrationResults`

| Id | ValidationOutcome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Awaiting confirmation |
| 2 | Confirmed |

`dbo.UserNotes`

| Id | Message | RegistrationResultFk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | it's a test | 1 |
| 2 | it's a test 2 | 2 |

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know very well HiLo of NHibernate, as far as I read is some sort of table where NHibernate manage and gest the ids of tables. If you inspect your SQL Server tables you have a column per each table as Id INT (or BIGINT), correct?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the values of existing `id` s in the database to remove "gaps" created by nhibernate and give you more room still using the `int` datatype, and update all foreign keys using these values? Or can you accept a change to the id datatype from `int` to a `bigint identity` column (where the data type change would affect client applications but is much easier to do on the database side)?

Comment: Max, yes, each table has `int` `id`. But this `int` is shared between tables. For example. I have table `dbo.users`. It has a row, with id 1. And I have another table called `dbo.permissions` which starts with `id` 2. It is, because hilo uses shared `id`. So that's why it's very scary. Because we have 20+ tables which uses shared `id` and it's increasing very fast.

Comment: allmhuran, yes, I want to remove gaps, this happened because of how hilo manages shared `ids`. We have some relations between tables, and we want to keep them. Changing from `int` to `bigint` would be temporary solution. Because `id` still will be shared between tables.

Comment: If you are expanding the size (datatype) of the ID column, why do you want to renumber the IDs as well?  You don't need to do both to fix your stated problem and doing both is *a lot* more work than just doing one or the other.

Comment: This is a very difficult thing to automate and get exactly right, just for one ID column from one (and its referenced columns and tables), and it's FK and it's triggers, and any View, sProcs and/or functions that reference that column.  Doing it for an entire database is a phenomenal job that a professional DBA/consultant would take weeks to plan, script and prepare for, even with tools to assist.  I did this several times in my career and if there were FKs involved, just validating the process can take a week.

Comment: [This article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/changing-data-types-large-tables-int-bigint-conundrum/) describes the process that one professional DBA went through just to change the ID of *one* table.  I would follow much the same process myself.  For an entire database, this would be considered a *major* database operational project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you, to minimize impact, use `Sequences` that are equivalent of autoincrement fields but are stored outside the table.

Below simple example for a table

### Create the sequence

This code creates a sequence.
With SSMS you can also navigate to Database -> Programmability -> Sequence ==>
right-click New Sequence.

[Full Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax).

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.UserId 
    AS INT
    START WITH 1234 
    INCREMENT BY 1   
    ;
```

Read the syntax carefully to better set up your sequences, for example, you may want to set up the *CACHE* to increases performance minimizing the IOs required to generate sequence numbers

### Get ID

For getting the ID you must issue a Raw Query with NHibernate.
[NHibarnate Reference](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html)
[NEXT VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
public int GetNextUserId(Session session)
{
    var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.UserId");
    var result = query.UniqueResult();
    return Convert.ToInt32(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Max for your answer. I will try this when I will get access to my work laptop. I will re-invoke bounty if it expires. Also, I updated question with example, which may help to understand the problem more clearly

Comment: @3lvinaz I read the update I'm confident that my solution is good for your case.

Comment: To be clear, while this answer *could* be used in an answer that addresses the re-ordering, this answer itself does not address the re-ordering request.  Nor does it even address the automation of re-creating the tables and the foreign keys.